# Remove properties recursively

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Tortoise SVN has a choice to apply a propertie to all subfolder/subfiles recursively. Now I need to remove this properties. How can I do this recursively?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I did not find how to remove property recursively using GUI, but You can remove property using svn command line tool:

```
svn propdel PROPERTYNAME --recursive
```

where PROPERTYNAME is svn property(svn:ignore, svn:mime-type, etc...)

Comment: I have TortoiseSvn, where is svn.exe?

Comment: Hmm. I have tortoisesvn and subversion installed. svn.exe is in subversion distro:

http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=91

Comment: TortoiseSVN 1.7 and newer comes with a svn.exe, but it is optional and one has to explicitly select it during installation.

Comment: @MarkusSchaber or you can modify the TSVN instance through Programs and Features.

Comment: Just adding: if you want to list the properties: svn proplist * --rescursive

Comment: important **note**: this needs to be run on a **local working directory**