# Disable SVN keywords expansion for `svn checkout` / `svn update`?

Tags: svn, keyword, substitution

While it is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215651/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-keyword-substitution-for-svn-export/9207985#9207985) to do it with `svn export`, I found no way to do it with `svn checkout` or `svn update`.

`svn export` is not sufficient in my case because it does not seem to work with files that have been moved (syntax `@` to pass a PEG does not seem to help).

[Deleting the property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281453/remove-properties-recursively) does not work because I want to avoid committing (and I need to work on past versions of the files anyway so that would require branching ...).

Using `git-svn` [might work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74526766/git-svn-clone-removes-keywords-expansion-e-g-revision-id-author-etc-from-fi) but in past experiments I found it too slow to be usable on repos as big as the one I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

[People](https://lists.apache.org/thread/b1wm2xwt6wo0ocjwo3sfl60h21wwlt7d) have been asking for this feature for a long time (and [also](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-3305) for `svn diff`) but it does not seem to have been implemented.

There [might](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-2164) be a way to use `svn patch` for that (but it would be more complex than just passing a flag).

I ended up writing this Python script that modifies the files in place with the `svn:keyword` property. I got help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448300/custom-properties-in-svn-retrive-files-based-on-the-property/29560073#29560073)

**Warning**: modifies files in place so do work on a clean state (to be able to revert) and do not commit afterward, unless you really want it!

```
import subprocess
from xml.dom import minidom
import re

def undo_svn_keywords_expansions(root_dir_or_file):
    """ Modify files in place to change $Id: blahblah$ into $Id$ (for example)
        root_dir_or_file must be a file or directory within a svn checkout
        root_dir_or_file can be relative to current working directory
        this file (or, if it is a dir, all the files recursively contained
        inside of it) will be modified in place, using a regex on bytes
        (to avoid any text encoding problem)

        I tried hard to not need this, but:
        - I found no way to disable this expansion at checkout time
        - `svn export` does not work on urls that do not exists anymore (@rev
          does not seem to help)
        - unsetting the svn:keywords property is not sufficient: you need to
          commit the change (not possible in our case)
    """
    files_with_keywords_xml = subprocess.run(["svn", "propget", "svn:keywords", "--xml", "-R", root_dir_or_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    if len(files_with_keywords_xml.stderr) != 0:
        print("stdout: ", files_with_keywords_xml.stdout)
        print("stderr: ", files_with_keywords_xml.stderr)
        assert False
    files_with_keywords_xml.check_returncode()

    files_with_keywords = minidom.parseString(files_with_keywords_xml.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
    for file in files_with_keywords.getElementsByTagName('target'):
        file_path = file.getAttribute('path')
        properties = file.getElementsByTagName('property')
        svn_keyword_property = [p for p in properties if p.getAttribute('name') == "svn:keywords"]
        assert len(svn_keyword_property) == 1
        keywords = svn_keyword_property[0].firstChild.nodeValue.split(" ")
        keywords_as_bytes = [keyword.encode('utf-8') for keyword in keywords]
        keywords_sub_re = b'|'.join(keywords_as_bytes)

        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_to_read:
            file_contents = file_to_read.read()
            file_to_read.close()

            new_contents = re.sub(b"\$("+keywords_sub_re+b"):.*\$",
                                  b"$\\1$",
                                  file_contents)

            with open(file_path, 'wb') as file_to_write:
                file_to_write.write(new_contents)
```